# Control a solenoid position "in / out" with power only (no spring)

Tags: coil, solenoid, terminology, mechanical

I'm going to use a < 5$ [solenoid](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/323239655769) (vertically oriented) that has to press something.

If I understand well, a linear solenoid like this one:

[image]

moves to one precise position when powered, but when you turn the power off, *nothing happens* (in the case there is no spring ; I want to avoid / remove the spring for mechanical noise reasons out of context here - the system has to be very quiet).

Are there solenoids that:

- can move to position "completely out" when a certain voltage/current is applied
- can move to position "completely in" when another certain voltage/current is applied (or power applied to another pin)

i.e. **are there solenoids that can move back-and-forth with power only and no mechanical springs?**

**How are they called?**

NB: it's not a sourcing question (I can source myself) but I'm interested for the right terminology.

Comment: Are the springs really that noisy?

Comment: A latching solenoid?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Not sure about that terminology, the only I found for example on ebay is [that one](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/SOLENOID-LATCHING-PULL-INTERMITTENT-NWK-PN-B14-L-258-B-4/352409006947) with "latching" keyword, but it still has a spring.

Comment: "reversible solenoid" seems to get something that might be suitable.

Comment: @GlennWillen Nothing at all on ebay with these keywords, any other similar ideas?

Comment: Join two solenoids together so that they pull in opposite directions.

Comment: maybe you want a linear motor?

Comment: @Jasen Would you have an example (link) of such system with 2 solenoids connected together mechanically?